# Countif across prior columns by row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to count number of times a column value is greater than the prior columns. Only Columns BC&D should get a score.  I need to count the number of times a value in a given columns is greater any column to the left of it. i.e. ("C Score" compares value from columns A & B)

I have tried several versions of a list comprehension but nothing quite seems to be either the correct answer or usable format.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['B Score'] = ??
df['C Score'] = ??
df['D Score'] = ??

df_result = df
BScores = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
CScores = [2,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,1,0]
DScores = [2,0,1,3,3,3,0,0,1,0]
df_result['B Score'] = BScores
df_result['C Score'] = CScores
df_result['D Score'] = DScores
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You should probably set `np.random.seed()` prior to `randint` and provide the expected output from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
cols = df.columns.values
for i in range(1,len(cols)):
    col = cols[i]
    df[f'{col}_score'] = df.iloc[:,:i].lt(df.iloc[:,i], axis='index').sum(1)
```

data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D  B_score  C_score  D_score
0  37  12  72   9        0        2        0
1  75   5  79  64        0        2        1
2  16   1  76  71        0        2        2
3   6  25  50  20        1        2        1
4  18  84  11  28        1        0        2
5  29  14  50  68        0        2        3
6  87  87  94  96        0        2        3
7  86  13   9   7        0        0        0
8  63  61  22  57        0        0        1
9   1   0  60  81        0        2        3
```